# In R, how do I fit a student-t distribution to a set of empirical data?

Tags: r, data-visualization, density-function, kernel-smoothing, ggplot2

In R, I can fit a Probability Density Function to some empirical data using the following code:

```
energy <- rnorm(30) * 20
dens <- density(energy)
sum(dens$y)*diff(dens$x[1:2])
hist(energy,probability=TRUE)
lines(density(energy),col="red")
```

This produces the following graph of the Probability Density Function (PDF):

[image]

Howevever, I would like to fit a student-t distribution to this data instead. I'm wondering if its possible to do this and if its possible to plot the result like in the diagram above?

Comment: 'Fit a distribution to data' is equivalent to 'estimate the parameters from data'. Some common methods include maximum likelihood or method of moments. In R see, for example, the `fitdistr` function in MASS, which comes with R (`?MASS::fitdistr`), which has an example of fitting a t-distribution. It's certainly possible to do this with a t-distribution and plot the fitted distribution. However, see the warning in the example I mentioned.

Comment: For threads on this topic, please [search our site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=student+fit+distribution).

Comment: In addition, questions that are *only* about how to do something in R, when the OP does not have a substantive statistical question, are off-topic for CV (see our [help page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help)). That is, this Q would be off-topic even if it weren't a duplicate. Note that some of such questions might be on-topic on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), but they need to be legitimate programming questions, & not just 'what is the package / function for this'.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at function `fit.st` in package [QRM](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/QRM/QRM.pdf).

```
library(QRM)
fit.st(energy )
```